# Universal Link passes Apple validation (but doesn't work)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

I have been trying to set up Universal Links in my iOS app, but I'm encountering an issue where the app doesn't open when the Universal Link is tapped.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Hosted an Apple Associated Domains file on our server
2. Added Universal Links as a capability in Xcode
3. Specified the top-level domain name of our Universal Link in Xcode's capabilities tab like so: `applinks:ourwebsite.com`
4. Granted Associated Domains as a capability to our provisioning profile
5. Verified that our build scheme is using the appropriate provisioning profile
6. Enabled Universal Links in the Developer settings on our test device
7. Verified in the Diagnostics tab in iOS's Developer settings that our URL is a Universal Link that opens an installed app
8. Verified with a third-party validator that our URL is a Universal Link
9. Called `func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void)` in our `AppDelegate` (with breakpoints to verify that it's called)

After all this, the breakpoints never fire, and of course.

I have also tried cleaning the build, deleting derived data, and restarting Xcode, but the problem persists. I have checked for conflicting code or configurations and couldn't find any.

At this point, I'm unsure what might be causing the issue and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to further troubleshoot and resolve this problem.